# Debugging an external System command in Python

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/python



def copyPatchTempToPatchStage(destinationLoction):

 command='/usr/bin/python '+destinationLoction+'/PatchGen.py '
 print command
 executeCommand(command)




def executeCommand(command):

 p_output=subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
 p_output.communicate()
 p_output.wait()


if __name__ == '__main__':

 destinationLoction="/scratch/app/product/fmw/obpinstall/patching/patchGenerationPath/2015-12-28/T14_OPATCH/100005135/PATCH_TEMP"
 copyPatchTempToPatchStage(destinationLoction)
```

Now while debbuging the python file it does not enters the PatchGen.py

Is there any way to debug System commands

Comment: If you say what's going wrong (i.e. why you want to debug it) we may be able to suggest ways to solve that problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not possible to debug System commands.

If you write `p_output=subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)` Python does not know what is being run, it may be anything, not just a Python script.

What you want is `import`ing that module and running its `main` function from your current file. This will allow you to see debugging information.

Comment: If I will directly call the main function then wont be able to use popen pipe command

Comment: @RohanGala I just suggested a workaround. In general, it is not possible to debug popen pipe commands.